# -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 1256

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, crash

Over the last week, I've noticed a lot of `-[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 1256` crashes on iPhone 14 Pro devices running iOS 16.1.1.

The tableView where this problem originates has a constant number of rows and sections, so the datasource is never modified.

The crashes are also being reported to Crashlytics and Sentry, but never make it into the Apple Organizer.

Any idea what's going on? How can I resolve this issue?

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  App                            0x90e74 SettingsViewController.tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) + 4374285940 (SettingsViewController.swift:4374285940)
1  App                            0x91210 @objc SettingsViewController.tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) + 4374286864 (<compiler-generated>:4374286864)
2  UIKitCore                      0x14beec -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 1256
3  UIKitCore                      0x11f844 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsForRanges:createIfNecessary:] + 596
4  UIKitCore                      0x59350 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1088
5  UIKitCore                      0x58e44 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 148
6  UIKitCore                      0x5020 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1980
7  QuartzCore                     0x99ec CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 500
8  UIKitCore                      0xd21dc -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 292
9  UIKitCore                      0x3dc0c -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 816
10 UIKitCore                      0x3d8d8 -[UINavigationController _layoutTopViewControllerLookForNested:] + 436
11 UIKitCore                      0x1506dc -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:] + 892
12 UIKitCore                      0x150324 -[UINavigationTransitionView _notifyDelegateTransitionDidStopWithContext:] + 296
13 UIKitCore                      0x14f8e4 -[UINavigationTransitionView _cleanupTransition] + 536
14 UIKitCore                      0x14f634 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) conditionallyAnimate:withAnimation:layout:completion:] + 136
15 UIKitCore                      0x1a8c0c -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 1612
16 UIKitCore                      0x1a8270 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 2104
17 UIKitCore                      0x1a6fb4 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 608
18 UIKitCore                      0x1a6604 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 96
19 UIKitCore                      0x1a6568 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 172
20 UIKitCore                      0x5020 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1980
21 QuartzCore                     0x99ec CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 500
22 QuartzCore                     0x1d0a0 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 148
23 QuartzCore                     0x2e5b0 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*) + 456
24 QuartzCore                     0x635ec CA::Transaction::commit() + 652
25 QuartzCore                     0x4c8cc CA::Transaction::flush_as_runloop_observer(bool) + 88
26 UIKitCore                      0x504b44 _UIApplicationFlushCATransaction + 52
27 UIKitCore                      0x652740 _UIUpdateSequenceRun + 84
28 UIKitCore                      0xc99fd0 schedulerStepScheduledMainSection + 172
29 UIKitCore                      0xc9919c runloopSourceCallback + 92
30 CoreFoundation                 0xd5f54 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
31 CoreFoundation                 0xe232c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
32 CoreFoundation                 0x66210 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 244
33 CoreFoundation                 0x7bba8 __CFRunLoopRun + 836
34 CoreFoundation                 0x80ed4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
35 GraphicsServices               0x1368 GSEventRunModal + 164
36 UIKitCore                      0x3a23d0 -[UIApplication _run] + 888
37 UIKitCore                      0x3a2034 UIApplicationMain + 340
38 App                            0x8020 main + 41 (AppDelegate.swift:41)
39 ???                            0x1aa7e0960 (Missing)
```

Comment: Same problem here. Any solution?

Comment: Same here too...

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that there was a forced unwrapping deep inside my codebase. I would encourage you to search for any forced unwrapping.